# How to update MANIFEST in Wildfly when a class is changed

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I installed Eclipse and the Jboss Tools plugin with Wildfly. I Created an EAR project, a WAR project and two EJB jars projects `app1` and `app2`. I converted all the projects to Maven.

`app1` uses a class of `app2`. This compiles fine in Eclipse. But when I run the application, I get a  `ClassNotFoundException`.

The EAR pom.xml has the dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>app1</groupId>
        <artifactId>app1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mywar</groupId>
        <artifactId>mywar</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>app2</groupId>
        <artifactId>app2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If I add `app2.jar` to the classpath of `app1` in the MANIFEST, `app1` can find the class. The problem is that when I change a class in `app1`, the MANIFEST is recreated automatically, removing the classpath.

This works:

```
 Class-Path: app2-1.0.jar
```

I added to `app1` pom.xml a plugin to update the MANIFEST when the classes change, but it doesn't change anything:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>                                                       
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>app2-1.0.jar</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the problem in app1 pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Class-Path>app2-1.0.jar</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```